# Problem with Google App Engine Appstats

Tags: java, google-app-engine, appstats

I'm having an issue getting [Appstats](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats.html) to work correctly. Using /appstats or /appstats/stats ends up in an infinite loop that keeps redirecting back to /appstats/stats. This results in a 404 error saying the page isn't redirecting properly. Any idea what the issue is?

Below are the relevant lines in my web.xml. This is basically the same from the documentation [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats.html).

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appstats</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appstats</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/appstats/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>appstats</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.google.appengine.tools.appstats.AppstatsFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>logMessage</param-name>
        <param-value>Appstats available: /appstats/details?time={ID}</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>appstats</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<security-constraint>
    <display-name>appstatsConstraint</display-name>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>appstatsCollection</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/appstats/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

Here are the relevant lines in my appengine-web.xml. I've tried using both /appstats/stats and /appstats and they both have the same issue.

```
<admin-console>
    <page name="Appstats" url="/appstats/stats" />
</admin-console>
```

Below are the http headers showing the infinite redirect loop:

```
http://mysite.appspot.com/appstats/stats

GET /appstats/stats HTTP/1.1
Host: mysite.appspot.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:
1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/
*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: USER_LOCALE=en_US; JSESSIONID=POTIUPPpEmjHZoaNDWOSTA;
ACSID=AJKiYcHiwT8jH7e01V9O5iFu3kpBhDd3k3oBwwxylv5u0DbJ-
utvdpsgdb4Xim2WXwobkJmgTGGljvuh94_yVQ__-
VPnBsTtUAhRjSyZ2Lv3G7oUHAxTsCWHJIMChGT3-
XUyUNx8wxwvJisL_RTXH8Hc4TTLh_rVHm2k8gk8kgdbVZXexSV0K-
a3coELTecWIBolt0qLd5L-5vALm382KsqbHorPXqoZMPTvR_06g_mR1cbmF2Ihnk6YhP7no58BNpESM9HvFyKNKXODo39hF4oaZCcW0Q9TBqUMgsrBqlcIh3-
VvC7qvH0n_nAtrLTBbK_swnOFvCDcaf3whT9ty0CJ0VRNuNqIPOLHIeQAMgwXUNMr89P64EsgmuyONHR67glCQXEPOGXIaT1vcBJFwFoeNUqjdp824fHvoVhaL7Xlav-
LTIFuM3f_ymHLmibk57PRuXUYEaAG

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://mysite.appspot.com/appstats/stats
X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars: $0.645553
X-AppEngine-Resource-Usage: ms=18965 cpu_ms=27884 api_cpu_ms=0
Set-Cookie:
ACSID=AJKiYcF_YA7PB18b3T5OO7vEMo31f1hFhO8xKqFRiBUGrCr4YABAAyugZXcDfKMOM-
r0FiK8xlOPfQWx3tOWIJ6ueOqK89X8M9YfHIs8WKUcSs6PwNZSKV0HKxvbqeWxfZI_cpo2YoS73s_RPlyEvjaYLOf6iXPpWeYyKTAbSqPOEBnVnTk3oso6ur66CIj3FnN8vsHfbanqY4sbaRsNj9pLjWZco0quYLOK1fd4wRZx_oAvk3jOlfAj7BZ7p9L1bO8oVCMpVn19cwT6zvO2-9RSjfiOPAacw7Cg0MT30r7Fr7SCj7VcSPAye4lc7tb9KL9ztZEk0xbEX-9vC6vHM_VfPJ54Kb_FycxE6lACsKTE4hj0bOa2-2quaOP0NSxfoH9ozLlQQCsGhpWBnlu__W06D0GqDqxcDUu2HocYqWuLi91aoa-
aRTkqB_qo4aAa3OvHeKoFgwrS; expires=Mon, 12-Apr-2010 19:41:49 GMT;
path=/
Date: Sun, 11 Apr 2010 19:42:08 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 0
----------------------------------------------------------
http://mysite.appspot.com/appstats/stats

GET /appstats/stats HTTP/1.1
Host: mysite.appspot.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US; rv:
1.9.2.3) Gecko/20100401 Firefox/3.6.3 (.NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/
*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7
Keep-Alive: 115
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: USER_LOCALE=en_US; JSESSIONID=POTIUPPpEmjHZoaNDWOSTA;
ACSID=AJKiYcF_YA7PB18b3T5OO7vEMo31f1hFhO8xKqFRiBUGrCr4YABAAyugZXcDfKMOM-
r0FiK8xlOPfQWx3tOWIJ6ueOqK89X8M9YfHIs8WKUcSs6PwNZSKV0HKxvbqeWxfZI_cpo2YoS73s_RPlyEvjaYLOf6iXPpWeYyKTAbSqPOEBnVnTk3oso6ur66CIj3FnN8vsHfbanqY4sbaRsNj9pLjWZco0quYLOK1fd4wRZx_oAvk3jOlfAj7BZ7p9L1bO8oVCMpVn19cwT6zvO2-9RSjfiOPAacw7Cg0MT30r7Fr7SCj7VcSPAye4lc7tb9KL9ztZEk0xbEX-9vC6vHM_VfPJ54Kb_FycxE6lACsKTE4hj0bOa2-2quaOP0NSxfoH9ozLlQQCsGhpWBnlu__W06D0GqDqxcDUu2HocYqWuLi91aoa-
aRTkqB_qo4aAa3OvHeKoFgwrS

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Location: http://mysite.appspot.com/appstats/stats
X-AppEngine-Estimated-CPM-US-Dollars: $0.002243
X-AppEngine-Resource-Usage: ms=64 cpu_ms=93 api_cpu_ms=0
Date: Sun, 11 Apr 2010 19:42:08 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Server: Google Frontend
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: I'm using Java -- not python. This is the one line: <page name="Appstats" url="/appstats/stats" />. I've tried /appstats and /appstats/stats. It has the same issue.

Comment: Shot in the dark: Is it possible in your setup to try the default, i.e. just `/stats` (at least that's the default in the Python version)? Other than that, I'm afraid I can't be of much help. But with appstats being pretty new in the Java version, I wouldn't rule out a bug on Google's side.

Comment: Have you followed the instructions here? http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/appstats.html -- they don't mention anything about an <admin-console> element...

Comment: The <admin-console> element is just so there is a custom link in the admin console. I don't think it's really important, but I was asked what was in the app.yaml file (and the appengine-web.xml is the java version of that). I get the same issue if I go directly to the URL w/o using the admin console.

Comment: I added my web.xml configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out this was an issue with the URL rewrite filter configuration that I also had in my web.xml. I had to ensure that no rules matched `/appstats/*`. I edited my rewrite urlrewrite.xml to below.

```
<urlrewrite>
    <rule>
        <from>^(?!/appstats/)/(.*)$</from>
        <to last="true">/app/$1</to>
    </rule>
</urlrewrite>
```

`/app/*` is my Spring dispatcher servlet mapping.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for posting the answer. I have been hunting the google docs for the last one hour trying to figure out whats wrong and then I realized upon reading your post that I have the damn urlrewrite filter setup! Cheers!

Comment: No problem, glad to know I'm not the only one who screwed this up. :-)